# Package access level to class

Tags: java, access-modifiers

What is the access scope of a class when defined with no access specifier?
For example:

```
package com.foo.bar;

class MyFoo{
     // All Class definition
}
```

I know that such class is called `package class` as oppose to `public class`. So my question is from where can we access and use such class (as they seems to be accessible from no where). Can I access it from another public class of same package?
For example:

```
package com.foo.bar;

public class MyBar{
    MyFoo foo; // Compiler throwing and error at this line
    // Rest of definition
}
```

I have asked google but couldn't got a response from there.

Comment: have you imported the class?. What error?

Comment: Got it. As Task have mentioned in answer I am missing import statement. Therefore compiler was throwing an error saying
`cannot find symbol class MyFoo`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that class is available for elements of *same package*.
You can absolutely access it by *import* statement as you can't access it from anywhere directly (*means without importing*) like you can do that with `public class`.You have to add `import` statement.

```
import pack1.pack2.MyClass;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first class is *package-private* which means it's visible to other classes in the same package, so all in all your example should compile. Here's [the canonical tutorial link on Java access rules](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html).

It should *not* be necessary to `import ...` when classes are in the same package!

What's the error?

Cheers,

Comment: I think you mean import rather than include

Answer (score 0):

From The Java™ Tutorials [Controlling Access to Members of a Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)

> … If a class has no modifier
>   (the default, also known as package-private), it is visible only
>   within its own package (packages are named groups of related classes —
>   you will learn about them in a later lesson.)

Answer (score 0):

It is often crucial to limit (if not avoid) the use of concrete classes by client classes and rather rely on interfaces.
Indeed such dependencies on concrete classes make client code fragile with respect to the introduction of new concrete classes of the same kind (implementing the same interface).

The client classes will only declare variables or collections or methods typed with the interface and thus rely on polymorphic methods.
Then concrete classes can be *package-private* (but see the point on instanciation below) since the client classes only need the interface(s) that will typically be public.
The advantage of declaring a set of *package-private* concrete classes is that it helps preventing the introduction of careless dependencies to them.

One issue however is about creating instances of the concrete classes since the *new* operator is not polymorphic.
One thus needs to rely on sophisticated methods (dependency injection, creational patterns such as Prototype or some factory, involved tools such as Spring or Guice ...). Even then, package-level visibility can be too restrictive to apply those instanciation methods conveniently.